# Can be assembly.Location equal null?

Tags: c#

I find this code [here](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox/blob/3023da8b168ceef1c00e98c68910c54ee390fbae/XrmToolBox/Program.cs#L147).

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
if (assembly.Location == null)
{
  throw new NullReferenceException("Executing assembly is null!"); // Is it possible???
}
```

Can be `assembly.Location` equal null?

Comment: The [documentation doesn't describe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=netframework-4.8) it as returning null, although there is a situation where it can return an empty string. You could check the reference source if you wanted to be sure. Anyways, the exception message is wrong. The message should be "Executing assembly location is null". If the executing assembly were null (not sure if that could happen) you would get a NullReferenceException in your if statement.

Comment: maybe when the assembly is not referenced the location is null, so this code probably is to make sure the assembly is referenced because probably is used by other assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Documentation clearly states that Location [might return an empty string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location) ("")
2. Looking into source code you might might be interested in the following files:

a) [RuntimeAssembly.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeAssembly.cs)

```
[DllImport(JitHelpers.QCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void GetLocation(QCallAssembly assembly, StringHandleOnStack retString);
```

b) [assemblynative.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/assemblynative.cpp)

```
void QCALLTYPE AssemblyNative::GetLocation(QCall::AssemblyHandle pAssembly, 
QCall::StringHandleOnStack retString)
{
    QCALL_CONTRACT;
    BEGIN_QCALL;
    {
        retString.Set(pAssembly->GetFile()->GetPath());
    }
    END_QCALL;
 }
```

c) The last question is were can we find GetPath() implementation. Methinks it is here:
[peimagelayout.inl](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/peimagelayout.inl):

```
inline const SString &PEImageLayout::GetPath()
{
    LIMITED_METHOD_CONTRACT;
    return m_pOwner?m_pOwner->GetPath():SString::Empty();
}
```

And it seems like it **does not return nulls** but empty strings.
I am not at all strong in C++ so it would be nice if somebody confirm my assumption.

Comment: RuntimeAssembly is only one of the concrete implementations of the Assembly base class.  AssemblyBuilder is another one, for example, it doesn't have a Location.  Anything is possible in a custom hosting scenario.

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() always returns RuntimeAssembly: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.CoreCLR.cs